# can't run an react-native new project on android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When I try to run my project using `react-native run-android` it shows me this error:`error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.`

Also, when I run from Android Studio it shows this error:`ERROR: Android dependency 'org.webkit:android-JSC:r245459' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported`

This is my package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "churchmap",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I can't understand why don't work

Comment: try to execute this one on the terminal that you run the project: export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/cosminciolacu/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replaced maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } with maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }, then I downloaded jetifier npm install --save-dev jetifier and ran npx jetifier. That solved my problem :)

Comment: I have local.propeties file created and in this file is `sdk.dir=/Users/cosminciolacu/Library/Android/sdk`